# Reading image from URL - performance problems?

Tags: java, image, url, inputstream, outputstream

could someone check the code below and see if would be any thing better to do. The thing that I'm truly worried about is performance, would I have any with this? If not, is there any thing that I could do better to improve the code readability?

```
try {

    URL url = new URL("http://www.pudim.com.br/SiteBuilder/UploadUsers/pudim.com.br/pudim.jpg");
    URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
    String type = uc.getContentType();
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();
    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    // not important :) ...
} catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (AmazonClientException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any considerations are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `ImageIO` to read AND write the image?  Why not just use the `URLConnection`s `InputStream` to read the content?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have all the normal performance issues one would have when reading from a URL - poor connectivity/bandwidth/availability; the same solutions apply as well - create and use a local cache, do loading/heavy IO on a background thread (to avoid blocking the main UI thread).  You'll want to wrap your code in a standalone parameterized function as well...

You're not actually doing anything with your resulting `InputStream` in this example - perhaps consider whether they're necessary overall to get what you want - as is, you're loading the entire image into memory each time - not totally necessary if all you're doing is saving it to disk.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is just to download the image I would just use the [`BufferedInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html)
to allow it to read the data as fast as possible from the network underneath.

They you can similarly use a [`BufferedOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) to dump it out to a `FileOutputStream` of your local file.

No need to do any image processing.

Comment: Actually the purpose of these code is to save an image, that comes from an URL, into my AWS S3 bucket.

that's why I have 'byte[] bytes = os.toByteArray();', with this I get the length of the file.

Since I don't know much about InputSream and OutputStreams, I have asked in order to check if I was doing something stupid :)

Comment: OK so if you wish to have a byte array in memory with the file contents first, just use the `BufferedInputStream` to read data fast, and write it to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` as you are doing. Then once you get the size of the array of the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and you confirm you want to write it to the storage just use the `BufferedOutputStream` to do `write(bytes)` where bytes is the array from the `ByteArrayOutputStream.` You don't need to use ImageIO it will just do image processing in vain.

Comment: By the way, you do know that `URLConnection` actually provides a method `getContentLength()` which gives you the size of the content you are going to receive right? It is a bit webserver dependent though and sometimes it is not always provided (HTTP 1.1 requires it, but some implement it incorrectly)